# Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly - xampp

Tags: xampp

I have not found the solution to this problem:

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
Apache-improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Apache- Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
Apache- the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
Apache- If you need more help, copy and post this
Apache- entire log window on the forums
```

I have changed port numbers, dealt with firewall, and even installed the old version of xampp and suitecrm to import and export and nothing.

Comment: locate your XAMPP Apache log \xampp\apache\logs\error.log, post it here

Comment: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 341351 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Mar 14 18:37:14.952959 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 380] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Mar 14 18:37:15.015426 2018] [core:warn] [pid 4600:tid 380] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

Comment: [Wed Mar 14 18:37:15.077891 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 380] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 341351 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: try to increase the memory_limit in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error appeared after I changed the external drive on which I saved my projects. Previously it was F: and now it is G:. But in the httpd-vhosts.conf file I forgot to change the virtual host path. After changing to G: in the httpd-vhosts.conf file, XAMPP started working.
Or when the computer had too few resources, e.g. RAM.